# Plugin action listener for com.intellij.ide.actions.NewProjectAction

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to write an IntelliJ plugin that does some actions after [`com.intellij.ide.actions.NewProjectAction`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/java/idea-ui/src/com/intellij/ide/actions/NewProjectAction.java) is run. I can import other actions from the `com.intellij.idea.actions` package (such as [`AttachDirectoryAction`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/lang-impl/src/com/intellij/ide/actions/AttachDirectoryAction.java)), but not `NewProjectAction`. Snooping around the [source code on github](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community), the actions I am able to import are located in the `lang-impl` directory, while the `NewProjectAction` and other actions I can't import are in the `java/idea-ui` directory. How would I go about listening for `NewProjectAction` since it is implemented in a different module?

Answer (score 2):

You could add an [application listener](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/plugin-listeners.html#defining-application-level-listeners) on the [`AnActionListener` topic](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/223ff19ba4e69df53a193c07f7a784355e8021ac/platform/editor-ui-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/actionSystem/ex/AnActionListener.java).

Create a listener:

```kotlin
class NewProjectListener : AnActionListener {

    override fun afterActionPerformed(action: AnAction, event: AnActionEvent, result: AnActionResult) {
        super.afterActionPerformed(action, event, result)
        if (action is NewProjectAction) {
            println("Created new project")
            // Do your actions
        }
    }
}
```

And add the listener in your `plugin.xml`:

```xml
<applicationListeners>
    <listener class="<package>.NewProjectListener"
              topic="com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.AnActionListener"/>
</applicationListeners>
```

Note that the topic in `plugin.xml` is the `AnActionListener` interface which our listener implements.

---

Because you didn't specify what kind of actions you want to do after creating a new project, and this doesn't feel very efficient, here are a few other ideas that might be a better solution to what you are trying to achieve:

- [StartupActivity](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/79bf4b1ae08162fb2154fd0d058d8a8e31fa23a2/platform/core-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/startup/StartupActivity.kt) via the extension point [postStartupActivity](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/intellij-platform-explorer/extensions?extensions=com.intellij.postStartupActivity).
- [ProjectManagerListener](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/b3c7a027d44132510a7923f43ef6584e2333be87/platform/projectModel-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/project/ProjectManagerListener.java), use in a similar way as above, override the method you need.
- [Adding new steps to the project wizard](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/adding-new-steps.html)